# Uma api em rest continua a correr se perder a conexão com o cliente

Tags: php, api

Estou a criar uma api em rest que quando um utilizador usa a api esta altera alguns valores dentro de um ficheiro json varias vezes no entanto não sei se quanto um cliente perde a conexão com a api esta para imediatamente ou se só verifica que esta perdeu a conexão quando esta envia uma resposta

Answer (score -1):

A requisição recebe um "Connection Failure" como resposta ao tentar conectar com o server quando ele não está funcionando, portanto não completará a tarefa

Comment: Eu percebo que se caso o servidor esteja a não a funcionar este envia um connection failure quando tenta connectar a minha duvida é mais se o cliente envia um pedido á api é durante o pedido o cliente perde a conexão com o servidor, por falha de rede por exemplo.